# show that if $p>1, x>1$, then for all real values of $p, x^p - 1 > p(x-1)$?

Tags: calculus

show that if $p>1, x>1$, then for all real values of $p, x^{p} - 1 > p(x-1)$?

I know this is true but can someone show me how to manipulate the inequality step by step so I can prove it?

Comment: Is $p$  an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^p - px$. Then $f'(x) = p(x^{p-1} - 1)$. For $x > 1$, we have
$$p - 1 > 0 \implies x^{p-1} > 1 \implies f'(x) > 0$$
which shows for $x > 1$, we have 
$$f(x) > f(1) \implies x^p - px > 1 - p \implies x^p - 1 > p(x - 1)$$

Answer (score 3):

By the Lagrange theorem, there exists $c \in (1,x)$ such that
$$
\frac{x^p-1}{x-1} = p c^{p-1} > p.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^p - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{p-1} + \ldots + x + 1) > (x - 1)(1 + 1 + \ldots + 1) = (x-1)p$$

Comment: "Is pp an integer?"

Oops.  Didn't think of that.  If not, well... we define rational powers as integer powers of roots and the result holds.  And we define real powers as limits and we show the result holds.  But that's tedious and SRX's solution is simpler after all.